# FreeBSD and DD a Blu-Ray Disk

Tags: freebsd, blu-ray

How do I mount a Blu-Ray Movie Disk in FreeBSD 10?  I don't need to decrypt the disk, I just need to access the data and copy it to an ISO files so I can transfer the image to another a windows computer to decrypt there with MakeMKV.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you don't want to mount it, only to access the raw data of the disk.What have you tried so far? Maybe using `dd`, `ddrescue` or even `cat` to copy the data?

Answer (score 0):

To create an image you do not generally need to mount the storage device. For example, to create an image using dd you would run:

```
dd if=/dev/cd0 of=file.iso bs=2048
```

which creates a file "*file.iso*" in the current directory. Note you will need access to the /dev/cd0 device to do this. As suggested by zuazo, there are other options (such as ddrescue) that will do the same thing.

If you do indeed want to mount the device, you should be able to do so with:

```
mount -t udf /dev/cd0 /mnt
```

assuming UDF format is being used.